# What constitutes a python environment

Tags: python

I have been working with python for a few years now and theres a concept I still can't get through my head.

What constitutes a fully operational environment? By which I mean what are the minimum system settings which are required to be able to start a python session and import modules?

I have noticed that two environment variables are important for python in Windows. They are as follows

`PATH`

`PYTHONPATH`

I am sure other things are necessary, and it is those things that I am asking about. Is there an official guideline for this in the python docs? What do third party environment tools like `conda` and `virtualenv` use? Is is possible to do away with such tools and construct environments oneself?

Comment: I'm not sure what the minimum setup for windows is, but the relevant environment variables are here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#using-on-envvars

Comment: I'm not sure if the term means my on it's own.  conda and virtualenv have their own definitions (e.g. links to the appropriate python interpreter, scripts to set up various shells' environment variables, sets of installed packages), while tools like docker would go further and bake a copy of the filesystem/OS into it

Comment: Python can be embedded into a C++ application, further broadening this question. Or are we talking strictly about _interpriter environments_?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` does not need to be set and even `PATH` doesn't if you use the full path to `python.exe` to start the Python program.